# Htaccess redirection a specific ip address to a file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain where I am installing wordpress, but I would like to see the wordpress index1.php only to my ip adress while is under construction.
Meanwhile the other visitors they will continue to see index.html as normal.

Redirection:

- From ip 1.2.3.4 requests to domain.com redirect to domain.com/index1.php
- From other ips requests to domain.com redirect to domain.com/index.html

I tried to do this by modifing .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index1.php [L]
```

I tried few variations but no one works as expected

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /index1.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /index1.php [L]
```

but it could be the rewrite condition.

[mod_rewrite reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =1.2.3.4
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.html)?$ index1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule ^(?:index1\.php)?$ index.html [L,NC]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =1.2.3.4
RewriteRule . index1.php [L]

RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but it doesn't work either. I thought that this would be the easiest way.

Comment: Make sure you're getting exact same IP that you have in .htaccess by printing all headers in a test php file

Comment: yes, I did so echo "remote_addr: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: ok so if IP is exactly what you have in .htacess, what error are you getting and what is the URL causing that?

Comment: In both cases, from the ip address and from other ip, are going to index.php

Comment: Sorry but is exact URL in browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220578/discussion-between-joe-and-anubhava).